# What is the difference between decreasing and reducing?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context

In a question referring to the statement

> *The average age at which people die of heart diseases is decreasing.*

The answer says that using *reducing* is preferable to using *decreasing*.

How does one decide between using *reducing* and *decreasing*, as both are similar in meaning?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I just came across a fine line between the two words, and I hope it works. It seems that in 'reducing', an external force is used.

When we say

He has been _______ the intake of sugar since he was diagnosed with diabetes.
(reducing / decreasing) --> I would use "reduced" because it is something done by him.

while

The number of students, appearing for this paper, is __________.
(reducing / decreasing)--> I would use "decreasing" as it's something not done by anyone.

Comment: I think it should be "He has______...." in place of "He has been_______...."

Comment: @ Ram Pillai i believe both can be used as the time reference is since

Comment: Oh Yes, He has reduced...& He has been reducing....(.) But I thought "He has reduced the intake of sugar since...." sounded better.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the active/passive nature of the terms pointed out in the other answer, the words are also distinguished in terms of whether they describe a reduction in quality or quantity. If something is decreasing, it is getting smaller in a quantitative sense. If something is reducing, it can also be diminishing in a qualitative sense.

One could say "he was reduced to a shell of a man" or "the city was reduced to rubble", both of which describe a qualitative change. You cannot "decrease" a city to rubble, because there is no quantitative change - there is still one city, but its character has been diminished. "Reduce" can also be used in a quantitative sense, however, so it may be a bit more versatile than "decrease".